# How to access Menu bar (File, Edit, View etc.) in Sublime-Text-3 from keyboard in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sublimetext3, menubar, ubuntu-18.04, alt-key

I am using Sublime Text 3 in Ubuntu 18.04. Actually, I hided the Menu bar of Sublime Text 3. Now I want to use Menu bar. But I cannot access the Menu bar from using ALT key.
I have also tried re-installing that. But it didn't work.

Comment: Select `View: Toggle Menu` from the command palette (`ctrl+shift+p`) to turn the menu back on.

Comment: Thank you so much!